# How do I set the sidebar color in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Seems there are two colors to the sidebar in vscode light and dark.  I am wanting to use the solarized light theme but have a dark sidebar.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 32):

VS Code support workbench theming now, check [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_12#_workbench)

Which means, in settings we can do as below to customise colours,

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
   "sideBar.background": "#111111"
 }
```

Answer (score 17):

Create a file named settings.json in the .vscode folder, and enter the below lines:
you can change icons color in sidebar, comments, background color or even more as depicted in the attached picture.

[image]

```
{
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "activityBar.background": "#6ff304",
    "titleBar.activeBackground": "#69e024",
    "titleBar.activeForeground": "#5809ce",
    "icon.foreground": "#91ff00",
    "symbolIcon.colorForeground": "#ff0000",
    "icon.colorForeground": "#ff0000",
    "activityBar.inactiveForeground": "#524747"
  },

  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
      {
        "scope": [
          "comment",
          "comment.block.documentation",
          "comment.block.documentation.js",
          "comment.line.double-slash.js",
          "storage.type.class.jsdoc",
          "entity.name.type.instance.jsdoc",
          "variable.other.jsdoc",
          "punctuation.definition.comment",
          "punctuation.definition.comment.begin.documentation",
          "punctuation.definition.comment.end.documentation"
        ],
        "settings": {
          "fontStyle": "italic",
          "foreground": "#78108a"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: It's under Code folder now - %appdata%\Code\User\settings.json

Comment: How did you get the blue folder icons in your sidebar?

Comment: This should be famous! The only more cool thing would be if somebody took this and made a webpage showing the setting like on clicking an element and one could build-out their workspace color customizations.

Comment: where can I find more illustrated picture like this?

Answer (score 8):

**here is customization for each vs code window** : it is helpful if you work on many project on different different vs code instanse

add a folder `.vscode` in your project root folder and add a file `setting.json` in .vscode folder
then add your favorite style below example is the result of attache screenshot

```
{
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "activityBar.background": "#14b197",
        "statusBar.background": "#333"
      }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Create a file named `settings.json` in the `.vscode` folder, and enter the below lines:

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Light+",
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "activityBar.background": "#e7e7e7",
        "activityBar.foreground": "#000000"
    }
}
```

The color value `#e7e7e7` (for activity bar background) separates it from other parts so it stands out.

For global settings, add these lines in global `settings.json` file.
My global `settings.json` looks as below:

```
{
    "workbench.editorAssociations": {
        "*.ipynb": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb"
    },
    "python.pipenvPath": "C:\\Users\\abhi\\anaconda3\\envs",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Light+",
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "activityBar.background": "#e7e7e7",
        "activityBar.foreground": "#000000"
    },
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "git.confirmSync": false,
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt"
}
```

The global `settings.json` can be found at:

```
Windows: %APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json
mac:     $HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json
Linux:   $HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json
```

Visual Studio Code will now look as below:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I guess you may want to set the color theme of the **activity bar**, but that of the sidebar is *the same*.

You can refer to [Theme Color | Visual Studio Code Extension API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color) to check the corresponding properties of each element so that you can customize the one that you want to modify (tip: using <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> on macOS or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> on Windows and Linux to search keywords in that webpage would be more convenient).

Here are my Visual Studio Code color scheme configurations in the `settings.json` file (just for reference):

```json
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Light+",
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "activityBar.background": "#f4f4f4",
        "activityBar.foreground": "#000000"
    }
}
```

Result:

[You can click this link to take a look at my Visual Studio Code color scheme.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lojDx.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

If you have auto/manual switching dark/light color themes in the OS and to customize a specific theme only, use the following syntax:

```json
{
    "window.autoDetectColorScheme": true,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Light+",
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "[Default Light+]": {
            "activityBar.background": "#f3f3f3",
            "activityBar.foreground": "#333333"
        },
        "[Default Dark+]": {
            "activityBar.background": "#333333",
            "activityBar.foreground": "#f3f3f3"
        }
    }
}
```