# Is it possible to change the colors of Views (primary sidebar "tabs") in VS Code individually?

Tags: visual-studio-code

is there a way to change background color of file explorer sidebar? But only this, not whole sidebar background?
Im switching between few sidebars (file explorer, git, workspaces) and I always need to focus on it and recognize what panel is now opened. Loosing precious miliseconds :D

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42129268/how-do-i-set-the-sidebar-color-in-vscode) answer your question?

Comment: Not really, it sets background for whole sidebar: sideBar.background. It looks like there is no specific tag for "file explorer" or any other way how to specify current tab/pane/subwindow.

Comment: I made a suggestion. See if it helps

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible. All I'm aware of is the answers to [How do I set the sidebar color in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42129268/11107541), which are for Views in general (not able to target specific Views).

You could [raise a feature-request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md).